# Is it possible to overlap different modules in python?

Tags: python, pygame, vpython

I've made a simulation using Vpython and I want to create a GUI using PYGAME. 
I was wondering if it's possible to embed that simulation made using Vpython into my GUI.

Comment: did you see screenshot in [New Features in VPython 6](http://vpython.org/contents/new_features.html) ? It seems it uses `wxPython` to create GUI - http://vpython.org/contents/docs/controls.html . `PyGame` doesn't have widgets for GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about pygame, but I'm guessing that the interaction processing of pygame and the interaction processing of VPython would be incompatible with each other.